# SQL Lag() with where clause

Tags: sql, lag, partition

I have a table like this -

| row_no | Movie. | movie_start_time | movie_end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-01 01:00:00 | 2021-02-01 02:00:00 |
| 2 | B | 2021-02-01 01:00:00 | 2021-02-01 02:00:00 |
| 3 | A | 2021-02-01 01:30:00 | 2021-02-01 02:30:00 |
| 4 | A | 2021-02-01 01:30:00 | 2021-02-01 02:30:00 |
| 5 | A | 2021-02-01 02:15:00 | 2021-02-01 03:15:00 |
| 6 | B | 2021-02-01 02:15:00 | 2021-02-01 03:15:00 |
| 7 | A | 2021-02-01 04:15:00 | 2021-02-01 05:15:00 |

I want to add one additional column to the table which has difference between previous play time and current play time for the same movie. I also have a condition that **previous play time and current play time shouldn't be overlapping.** So in above scenario, results should look like below:

| row_no | Movie. | movie_start_time | movie_end_time. | last_play |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2021-02-01 01:00:00 | 2021-02-01 02:00:00 | - |
| 2 | B | 2021-02-01 01:00:00 | 2021-02-01 02:00:00 | - |
| 3 | A | 2021-02-01 01:30:00 | 2021-02-01 02:30:00 | - |
| 4 | A | 2021-02-01 01:30:00 | 2021-02-01 02:30:00 | - |
| 5 | A | 2021-02-01 02:15:00 | 2021-02-01 03:15:00 | 15 minutes |
| 6 | B | 2021-02-01 02:15:00 | 2021-02-01 03:15:00 | 15 minutes |
| 7 | A | 2021-02-01 04:15:00 | 2021-02-01 05:15:00 | 60 minutes |

I tried writing below query for getting the previous movie_end_time so that I can calculate the difference later :

```
select movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time, lag(movie_end_time) over (partition by movie order by movie_start_time) prev_end_time from table where prev_end_time <= movie_start_time
```

But this doesn't work since we can't add where clause with window functions. Is there any other way to solve this problem ?

Comment: `select * from (<that query of yours>) t where prev_end_time <= movie_start_time`?

Comment: well are you sure the fifth row is correct? because it is overlapping with another movie A in the 4th row.

Comment: @GSerg That won't work as lag will just give me immediate previous row, I need immediate previous row which satisfies the condition prev_end_time <= movie_start_time

Comment: @ARAT I think the example I chose was little confusing - 15 minutes on the 5th row is the difference from non-overlapping previous record - which is the 1st row

Answer (score 0):

So I used postgreSQL to create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 (
  row_no INT,
  Movie CHAR,
  movie_start_time timestamp,
  movie_end_time timestamp
);
```

and insert the records into this table:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(1, 'A', '2021-02-01 01:00:00', '2021-02-01 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(2, 'B', '2021-02-01 01:00:00',  '2021-02-01 02:00:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(3, 'A', '2021-02-01 01:30:00',  '2021-02-01 02:30:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(4, 'A', '2021-02-01 01:30:00', '2021-02-01 02:30:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(5, 'A', '2021-02-01 02:15:00', '2021-02-01 03:15:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(6, 'B', '2021-02-01 02:15:00', '2021-02-01 03:15:00');
INSERT INTO table1 (row_no, Movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time) VALUES(7, 'A', '2021-02-01 04:15:00', '2021-02-01 05:15:00');
```

Then what you want is:

```
select row_no, movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (movie_start_time - prev_end_time)::INTERVAL)/60 AS last_play FROM 
(select row_no,movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time, lag(movie_end_time) over (partition by movie order by movie_start_time) AS "prev_end_time"
from table1) t
where prev_end_time <= movie_start_time
ORDER BY movie_start_time
```

[image]

Comment: In your results, 5th row is missing from the expected result. You are just checking immediate previous record for that movie. But I need immediate previous record for the movie where prev_end_time <= movie_start_time.
In the case of 5th row, the immediate previous record satisfying the condition would be 1st row

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with below query :

```
with a as 
(select row_no,movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time, 
array_agg(movie_end_time) over (partition by movie order by movie_start_time
 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) AS prev_end_time from `table1`),

b as (select row_no,movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time,
case 
when prev_end_time is null then null
else (select max(i_prev_end_time) from unnest(prev_end_time)i_prev_end_time 
where i_prev_end_time <= movie_start_time)
end previous_end_time from a)

select row_no,movie, movie_start_time, movie_end_time,
 unix_seconds(movie_start_time) - unix_seconds(previous_end_time) last_run from b
```